# Query to pull the previous 1 minute from the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (sysdatetime) - Define query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Been trying to do a query that will result in the previous 1 minute from the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with no duplicates. Currently, getting duplicates of the same `DeviceNumber` and `PrinterId` I have tried `DISTINCT` but that will not run the query. Also, if I run this query it will result into 36k+ rows. Would like it to min that to what is current with the timestamp.

This is on MS SQL Server 2014

Query as follows:

```
SELECT b.[PrinterId],b.[DeviceNumber],FORMAT (t.[ReportDatetime], 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as Date,t.[PrinterStatusText]
FROM [PrinterStatusReports] t, [MV_DevicesServerPortsAndPrinters] b
WHERE t.[ReportDatetime] < DateADD (MINUTE, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and t.[PrinterStatusText] LIKE 'Not Ready To Print- Not Reachable%'
```

Current result:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: share both table structure to help you with the join for avoiding dups

Comment: also, convert performs better than format. https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: Thanks! That is much faster and cleaner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Duplicates" are likely caused by your incorrect join - which would be more obvious if you did not use the old and error-prone method of joining in the FROM clause. E.g.

```
from PrinterStatusReports as t inner join MV_DevicesServerPortsAndPrinters as b
on t.?? = b.?? 
where t.ReportDatetime ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you well, the only thing you have to do is to change the WHERE condition, currently you are selecting all records with a (reportdatetime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 minute). As I understand you want all records with a reportdatetime > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1 minute).

```
    SELECT b.[PrinterId],b.[DeviceNumber],FORMAT (t.[ReportDatetime], 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as Date,t.[PrinterStatusText]
    FROM [PrinterStatusReports] t, [MV_DevicesServerPortsAndPrinters] b
    WHERE t.[ReportDatetime] > DateADD (MINUTE, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and t.[PrinterStatusText] LIKE 'Not Ready To Print- Not Reachable%'
```